# TCPサーバーはLISTEN状態のソケット一つでどうやって複数の接続を捌くのでしょうか？

Tags: tcp, network

[RFC793 に書かれている状態遷移図](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0402/13/news096_3.html)（原文では[§3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.2)のFigure6）では、サーバー側は LISTEN ... ESTABLISHED ... CLOSED と遷移していくように書かれています。

リモートエンドポイントを指定せずに LISTEN 状態に入ったサーバーは、クライアントからの接続を受けてリモートエンドポイントを確定し、 ESTABLISH 状態に入ります。**しかしその後もサーバーは他のエンドポイントからの接続を待ち受けています。**

この流れは「 LISTEN 状態のソケットが1つあり、接続を受けると ESTABLISHED に遷移する」では説明がつかないように思うのですが、どのように考えるとよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> この流れは「 LISTEN 状態のソケットが1つあり、接続を受けると ESTABLISHED
>   に遷移する」では説明がつかないように思うのですが、どのように考えるとよいのでしょうか？

「コネクション」と「ソケット」の区別をしてください。
その状態遷移図は「コネクション」の状態を示しているもので、「ソケット」の状態ではありません。

§1.5. Operation

> Concatenated with the network and host addresses from the internet
>   communication layer, this forms a socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely
>   identifies each connection.

§2.7.  Connection Establishment and Clearing

> A local socket may participate in many connections to different
>   foreign sockets.

ひと組のソケット（つまりローカルのソケットとリモートのソケット）によってコネクションを識別しています。
ソケットが1つであっても、コネクションが1つであるとは限りません。1つのソケットが複数のコネクションに紐付けられていてもよいのです。

Comment: コネクションの状態遷移図ではCLOSED..LISTENも書かれているものの、実際にはリモートソケットが決まるまでコネクションは存在せず、接続を受けてリモート側が決まったときにはじめてLISTEN状態のコネクションが生まれ、すぐさまSYNを受け取る、ということでしょうか？

Comment: いいえ、接続される前からLISTEN状態のコネクションは存在しますよ。イメージとしては、LISTEN状態のコネクションが接続を受けると、次の接続を待ち受けるために新しいLISTEN状態のコネクションが追加されると考えれば分かりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: netstatで見ると `0.0.0.0:0` 宛にLISTENING状態のエントリがあり、接続を受けると個別のエントリが増えるようですから、確かにそんな感じですね。なるほど。

Answer (score 3):

ざっくり言うと、仕様と矛盾しない範囲で工夫して実装されているということですよね。

> しかしその後もサーバーは他のエンドポイントからの接続を待ち受けています。

そもそも、RFC 793 で言及されている TCP のユーザインタフェースは、BSD Socket API を想定したものではなく、以下のような単純なものです。

- OPEN
- SEND
- RECEIVE
- CLOSE

RFC に記載されている TCP コネクションの状態遷移図に記載されているイベントも、このインタフェース（コマンド）の通りですよね。

> この流れは「 LISTEN 状態のソケットが1つあり、接続を受けると ESTABLISHED に遷移する」では説明がつかないように思うのですが

RFC 記載のユーザインタフェースには、BSD Scoket API の listen() -> accept() に相当するものはありませんので、説明がつかないのは当然といえば当然ですね。

実際には、h2so5 さんが回答されているように `ローカルソケットは複数の外部からのソケットに参加することができる` と記載されていますので、その前提をもとに考えると listen() したソケットが accept() した後に再度接続を待ち受けるという動きは RFC と矛盾していないというのが分かると思います。

Answer (score 0):

1. サーバプロセスは listen(2) で接続準備をカーネルに指示します。
2. その際、backlog で何個の接続待ちキューを作るかを指示します。たとえば 5 が指定されれば、5 個までの同時接続を受け付けることが可能です。
3. カーネルが１個の接続を受け付けると、5 個のうちの一つが SYN_RECEIVED を経て ESTABLISHED になります。ただし、他の 4 つの接続待ちキューの状態は相変わらず LISTEN のままです。

このように、１つのセッションでは無理でも、サーバホスト単位では ESTABLISHED と LISTEN が同時に共存可能ということになります。

Comment: それでは `accept()` するまでは他のクライアントからSYNが来ても反応しない、ということになりませんか？

Comment: fork() も execve() もしないですよ...

Comment: かなり間違った理解をしていたようですね。。。失礼しました。誤解を招くので、消しちゃった方がいいですか？

Comment: 3 と 4 が誤った情報ですので、それが修正されれば良いような気がします。あと、ハンドシェイクそのものはカーネルのプロトコルスタック内で完結する話なので、5 の accept() の内容も「確立済みの接続を取得する」のほうが正しいですかね。

Comment: 取り消し線の引き方がわからなかったので、書きなおしてしまいました。